# Remove and add ID key index from Access table in VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have an Access DB to automatically unify several CSV's in one table hourly (**Aux_Table1**) via macro (converted to VBA). Before unification, I run a query to clean **Aux_Table1** table, but Access is coded to **NOT** reuse KEY IDs, so each time I clear and unify CSV's, keys IDs keep counting.

The only method I know to "*reset*" ID KEY numeration is to delete an create manually this primary key in table's design mode, but I want to run it all automatically (it's part of a huge batch process).

How can I make this process via VBA to INCLUDE in my (VBA) function? (see this 4Mb [GIF](http://i.imgur.com/SHi6VJO.gifv) demo).

Example of my function:

```
Function MacroUnify()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "00_Borrar_Aux_Tabla1", acViewNormal, acEdit
    >>> Here I need to _REMOVE_ PrimaryKey from Aux_Tabla1 <<<
    >>> Here I need to _CREATE_ PrimaryKey from Aux_Tabla1 <<<
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "10_Crea_Tabla definitva", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "zzz_resultado_Combinado", "Excel97-Excel2003Workbook(*.xls)", "D:\access\fullCatalog.xls", False, "", , acExportQualityPrint
End Function
```

I've tryed with:

```
 CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE Aux_Tabla1 DROP CONSTRAINT PrimaryIndex"
 DoCmd.RunSQL "CREATE INDEX PrimaryIndex ON Aux_Tabla1(ID) WITH PRIMARY"
```

The function runs without problem, but the key index is still counting without reset.

PS: The index name is **PrimaryIndex** and the field name is **ID**

Comment: Not sure if I fully get what you mean, it will cause conflicts if you go back, but.... INSERT INTO Aux_Tabla1 ( id ) SELECT 0 AS Expr1;     I did alter table Aux_Tabla1 drop constraint primarykey
alter table Aux_Tabla1 drop constraint id
CREATE INDEX PrimaryIndex ON Aux_Tabla1 (ID) WITH PRIMARY
INSERT INTO Aux_Tabla1 ( id ) SELECT 0 AS Expr1;

Comment: There's no conflict because the table is wiped previously each time with the same function. Now it's working thanks to @Thomas G reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to reset the auto increment counter on your ID field

You can do it with this SQL instruction

```
CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE Aux_Tabla1 ALTER COLUMN ID COUNTER(1,1)"
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my purpose. Now IT WORKS with your code. Thank you! (I can't upvote you, my reputation is still below 15)

Comment: Congratulations ! (a useless comment doesn't hurt from time to time)

Answer (score 1):

The auto-increment property belongs to the column in the table, not to the index. So dropping and recreating the index has no effect. You would need to drop the Index first, then the column and then recreate both. - But you don't have to. 
There is an easier option:

```
ALTER TABLE Aux_Tabla1 ALTER COLUMN ID COUNTER(1,1)
```

This SQL statement will reset the auto-increment-counter on column "ID" to 1 and have it increased by 1 for each record. You can execute this either by `CurrentDb.Execute` or by `DoCmd.RunSQL`.

Be aware that you can change the structure of a table only if the table is not open at that time.

Comment: Thank you Phil, that's the solution indeed